# Links from folder html file to folder css file

Tags: html

Please could you help me with this styles.css and bootstrap.cssto the 531.html.

- css folder
      - styles.css file

  ```
   - bootstrap css folder

               - bootstrap.min.css file
  ```
- gallery folder

  - name folder

    - animals folder

      ```
         - 531.html file
      ```

Asyou can see i need a link solution to link the bootstrap and styles css files to the 531.html file.

Answer (score 0):

To go up multiple directories and then go to a subdirectory, you can do this.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href = "../../../css_folder/styles.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href = "../../../css_folder/bootstrap_folder/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Note that a single "../" goes up one directory. You can chain them and go up, then go down as usual with a "/folder".

To go to document root and traverse from there, you can use "/"

eg:

```
<.. href="/resource.css ..>
<.. href="/folder_1/resource.css ..>
```

This works for any file reference.

Comment: Great, please accept it as the answer if it solves the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

To link those two CSS files:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../css/style.css" />`

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />`